# Be suspicious of classes of which there is only one instance

Tags: oop, code-complete

tl;dr -- What does the below quoted paragraph mean?

> Be suspicious of classes of which there is only one instance.   A
>   single instance might indicate that the design confuses objects with
>   classes. Consider whether you could just create an object instead of a
>   new class. Can the variation of the derived class be represented in
>   data rather than as a distinct class? The Singleton pattern is one
>   notable exception to this guideline.
>
> McConnell, Steve (2004-06-09). Code Complete (2nd Edition)

Extended version:

I'm currently reading [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/), and I'm having trouble understanding the above mentioned paragraph.  For context, it's from Chapter 6 under guidelines for inheritance.  At first I thought this was advice against using Singletons, but I was obviously proven wrong by the time I got to the end of the paragraph.

I simply can't grasp what the author is trying to get through my thick skull.  For example, I don't know what he means by design confusing objects with classes, nor what that means in the context of having a class with only one instance.  Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording is pretty confusing there, but I believe what's meant is that sometimes a novice programmer might create a whole new type just to instantiate one object of it. As a particularly blatant example:

```
struct Player1Name
{
    string data;
};
```

There we could just use `string player1_name;` (or even an aggregate for multiple players) without creating a whole new type, hence the confusion of trying to use classes to model what new objects (new instances of existing types) can already do.

In such a case, a developer might spam the codebase with hundreds of new user-defined data types and possibly massive inheritance hierarchies with no potential for a single class to be reused beyond a single instance for every single new thing he wants to create when the existing classes generally suffice.

> <sub>**The real problem is not that the classes are being instantiated once,
>   but that their design is so narrowly applicable as to only be *worth* instantiating once.**</sub>

Classes are generally meant to model a one-to-many relationship with their instances (objects). They're supposed to be at least somewhat more generally applicable beyond a single instance of that class. Put crudely, a class should model a `Dog`, not your neighbor's specific pet dog, `Spark`. It's supposed to model a `Rectangle`, not a precise `Rectangle42x87` that is 4.2 meters by 8.7 meters. If you're designing things to be instantiated one time, you're probably designing them too narrowly and probably have existing things you can use instead.

A new data type is typically meant to tackle a class (category) of problems, so to speak, rather than one very precise one that calls for only one instance of that class. Otherwise your class designs are going to be one-shot deals that are just superficially creating classes all over the place to solve very individual problems with no potential for broader application whatsoever.

A singleton is an exception to the rule since it's not utilizing classes in this normal object-oriented kind of way. There it's deliberately setting out to create a single instance, lazy constructed, and with a global point of access. So there it's not by some accident and misunderstanding of object-oriented design that the developer created a class designed to be instantiated one time. It's a very deliberate and conscious design decision, so to speak, rather than a misunderstanding of how to use the tools.

Comment: "The real problem is not that the classes are being instantiated once, but because their design is so narrowly applicable as to only be worth instantiating once." -- This is both addresses what caused my original confusion, and answers the question in one elegant sentence.  Thank you!